# error in search function using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have this function  i want to select data within condition del_status =0
 i ready retrieve data but this condition not done 
what is error in this statment

```
public function SearchData($tablename,$data)
        {

            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from($tablename);
            $this->db->like('username', $data);
            $this->db->or_like('fullname', $data);
            $this->db->or_like('email', $data);
            $this->db->where('del_status','1');
            //$this->db->where('del_status'== '1');
            $sql = $this->db->get();
            return $sql->result();

        }
```

**and if i write this statement it work correctly**

```
        $select_query = "select * from $tablename where username like'%$data%' AND del_status ='1' ";
        $query = $this->db->query($select_query);
        return $query->result();
```

Comment: read about query grouping, that might help: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function search($data){
    $query = $this->db->where('del_status', 0)
                    ->group_start()
                    ->like('table_column', $data)
                    ->or_like('table_column', $data)
                    ->group_end()
                    ->get('tablename');


    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: then use $this->db->last_query(); for debug. I've tried this code and it worked perfect on my project.